# How to query data over multiple tables in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I'm trying to get an extract of data using two tables in Sql. I have an AddressBook table and a companies table. The AddressBook table has a foreign key called companyid which is the primary key in the companies table. The companies table has a column called accountno. How do I lookup all the addresses on the AddressBook table and find the accountno in the companies table using the companyId?

Please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: Did you try to write any query? If yes, post it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), i think you want left join. With left join you fetch the companies even if they dont have an adress, but i see you have an inner join tag so i will include that.

left join:

```
SELECT * FROM companies LEFT JOIN adressbook ON adressbook.companyid = companies.id
```

inner join:

```
SELECT * FROM companies INNER JOIN adressbook ON adressbook.companyid = companies.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from companies
inner join adressbook on adressbook.companyid = companies.id
```

if i read it correctly this is what you are looking for